# Does the Spanner Client support bulk inserts?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Google's Spanner supports SQL "bulk" Inserts e.g. from doco

INSERT INTO Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES(1, 'Marc', 'Richards'),
(2, 'Catalina', 'Smith'),
(3, 'Alice', 'Trentor');

However I cannot find any support for this in the Go Client. The Go Client "Statement" type supports single-row inserts and I have used the BatchUpdate() function to execute a batch of single-row inserts, but I cannot find any support for bulk-inserts.

Does the Spanner Client support bulk inserts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of ways that you can do that:

1. The one mentioned by yourself: Use the `BatchUpdate` method to execute a collection of individual `INSERT` statements. An [example can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-dml-batch-update#spanner_dml_batch_update-go).
2. You can execute an `INSERT` statement that inserts multiple rows by calling the `Update` method with a SQL string that inserts multiple rows. An [example can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-dml-getting-started-insert).
3. The **most efficient way** to insert a bulk of rows is to use **mutations** instead of DML. Use the `Apply` method to insert a collection of (insert) mutations. An [example can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-insert-data#spanner_insert_data-go)

Comment: Thankyou. As I have to use SQL in the current implementation option 2 is best - albiet I was looking for a client implementation of bulk insert rather than simply writing it in SQL as there is probably a small performance penalty - but it will work. Option 1 is really is not a bulk insert as it uses individual Insert statements which must all be parsed albiet not fully presuming Spanner shares the parsed SQL. Spanner is very fast nonetheless.  As you say the best solution is using mutations - I will need to bite the bullet and implement some parts in mutations rather than SQL. Cheers